# Pandas dataframe: Creating a new column based on data from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, `df`:

```
   foo         bar
0  Supplies   Sample X
1  xyz        A   
2  xyz        B
3  Supplies   Sample Y
4  xyz        C
5  Supplies   Sample Z
6  xyz        D
7  xyz        E
8  xyz        F
```

I want to create a new df that looks something like this:

```
   bar
0  Sample X - A
1  Sample X - B
2  Sample Y - C
3  Sample Z - D
4  Sample Z - E
5  Sample Z - F
```

I am new to Pandas so I don't know how to achieve this. Could someone please help?

I tried [DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows)
but no luck.

Comment: What is the exact logic? The supplies rows are the first chunk?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Basically I wanted to combine bar's "Sample" and "Sub-sample" together as strings, based on 'foo' data. The combined data should be displayed in the new column. F.e. 'Sample X' and its subs will be:
```   
    bar
0  Sample X - A
1  Sample X - B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
m = df['foo'].ne('Supplies')

out = (df['bar'].mask(m).ffill()[m]
       .add(' - '+df.loc[m, 'bar'])
       .to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
       )
```

Output:

```
            bar
0  Sample X - A
1  Sample X - B
2  Sample Y - C
3  Sample Z - D
4  Sample Z - E
5  Sample Z - F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
s = (df["bar"].mask(df.foo == "xyz").ffill() + "-" + df["bar"]).reindex(
    df.loc[df.foo == "xyz"].index
)

df = s.to_frame()
```

print(df):

```
           bar
1   Sample X-A
2   Sample X-B
4   Sample Y-C
6   Sample Z-D
7   Sample Z-E
8   Sample Z-F
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
g = df.groupby(np.cumsum(df.bar.str.startswith('Sample')))
pd.DataFrame([x[1].bar.values[0] + ' - ' +
             y for x in g for y in x[1].bar.values[1:]], columns=['bar'])
```

Output:

```
            bar
0  Sample X - A
1  Sample X - B
2  Sample Y - C
3  Sample Z - D
4  Sample Z - E
5  Sample Z - F
```